# Creating a dev environnement and the website won't see sub folder

Tags: php

A friend asked me to take there PHP website, and copy it locally to use as a dev envrionnement.

I don't do much PHP, but I agreed to give it a try.

Now I ran in an issue that I have a hard time getting around.

the website won't load CSS or JS script from subfolder.

root/css/..
root/js/...

Both those directory have a bunch of css/js files.

PHP files in subfolder seems to load just fine with includes. It only seems to be an issue with css and js.

When I check the network tab in IE, I see that they have an error 404 not found.

What could be the issue? It has to be something about my local install.

Info :
Hosted website : PHP 5.3 + MySQL
Local website : 5.6 + MySQL

I'M using Xampp.

Thank you!!

Edit -> More info : If I try to reach the css/js file directly via the url typed manualy in the browser, it doesn't work ether. Like if my apache didn't expose the js/css folders.

Comment: 404 means the path is wrong but without seeing any concrete info about the way you're including the files or clearer info about where the files are located compared to each other then it's hard to be certain

Comment: There could be many things wrong, unfortunately this question is too broad to receive a decent answer. We could try but anything we say is just speculation and most likely wrong and a waste of both of our and your time. The best approach to take right now is ask your friend to give you more details on how to configure their website e.g. do you need a virtual host? Do you need to set a specific root etc etc

Comment: Yeah my friend doesn't know anything about it, and the guy who created it is gone. So I'm out of information.

Can you point me where the root could be changed? So I can check if that is the issue.

Comment: By the way, just to add more info : If I try to access the css/js directly, with me manually typing the url in the browser, it doesnt work ether. Seems like my apache doesn't expose my css and js folders.

Comment: we can't tell you specifically what to do because we don't have any specific information about your apache setup and only have incomplete details of your folder structure. Unfortunately without any more relevant details, about the best we can suggest is that you read the apache manual.

Comment: What kind of info could I get to help people to help me? Is there an apache.ini files somewhere?

Comment: there should be a "conf" subdirectory (inside the folder where apache is installed, if you're using Windows - on Linux/Mac you might find it's elsewhere depending on your distro). Again, consult the manual for more details on the location and contents of the files. You may also be able to find GUI tools you can download to help you manage the webserver. Do a bit of googling.